# Jq installation error

Tags: shell, windows-installer, jq

I am using windows 10 home. I tried to install jq from https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/.

Downloaded `jq-win64.exe` file, but when i open it, it just opens and closes instantly . I want to run a `.sh` file which requires jq installed . Any help here.

Comment: I suggest you should install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) then install jq linux version with `apt-cyg install jq`

Comment: That's not an installer. That *is* the `jq` command. Rename it and stick it in `PATH`.

Comment: And then what? Coz I stuck it in PATH and it's still not working from the command line...

Answer (score 2):

After obtaining jq.exe (by whatever means), you would normally run it from a batch script or from the Windows command line.  See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_console

You may find it easier to use `jq` if you let "choco" install it for you (`choco install jq`).

To install `choco` is quite straightforward: https://chocolatey.org/install